# Compressing plists - NSPropertyListSerialization vs plutil?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, property-list

I wrote a simple command line tool for a special need to convert a specific ini file to a property list. I am using `NSPropertyListSerialization` to write the Dictionary to a binary property list file of 307kb. However when I write it to XML and after convert it using **plutil** to a binary property list the file is only 224kb in size.

I'd like to save as much data as possible but I also want to stay away from `NSTask`. The question here is, how would I achieve the same results from code as I achieve using `plutil`.

Comment: The first step would be finding out why there is a difference in size at all. Are you able to examine the two files and see where the extra space comes from? It might be hard with binary data though.

Comment: There's a very old but possibly related thread here: http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/153341-nspropertylistserialization-plutil-bloat-in-tiger-vs-jaguar.html. Apparently certain implementations will look for identical arrays and other items and handle that specially. But `NSPropertyListSerialization` does not do this because developers expect it to work as fast as possible. So I'm guessing plutil is doing this duplicate detection whereas NSPropertyListSerialization is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [this very old thread](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/153341-nspropertylistserialization-plutil-bloat-in-tiger-vs-jaguar.html), `plutil` will look for identical sub-trees such as arrays and unique them in the resulting plist. `NSPropertyListSerialization` used to do this a long time ago, but this was removed because the process is relatively slow and developers expect the serialization to work as fast as possible.

After googling around it doesn't look like it will be easy to find code to do this yourself. You may just have to deal with the small difference in size, or attempt to roll your own serializer.

Comment: Might be a fun github project for the summer then :)